# Error with protonvpn - "Expected at least 5 tokens for --menu, have 4"

Tags: command-line, openvpn

I have protonvpn installed and have been using it since ages without any trouble.

I have used this tutorial - https://www.tecmint.com/install-protonvpn-in-linux/
to install protonvpn

Now from today suddenly while trying to connect to protonvpn getting the following error -

`sudo protonvpn connect`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/protonvpn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/protonvpn_cli/cli.py", line 72, in main
    cli()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/protonvpn_cli/cli.py", line 134, in cli
    connection.dialog()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/protonvpn_cli/connection.py", line 83, in dialog
    country = show_dialog("Choose a country:", choices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/protonvpn_cli/connection.py", line 38, in show_dialog
    code, tag = d.menu(headline, title="ProtonVPN-CLI", choices=choices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dialog.py", line 2935, in menu
    return self._widget_with_string_output(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dialog.py", line 1728, in _widget_with_string_output
    code, output = self._perform(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dialog.py", line 1523, in _perform
    exit_code, output = self._handle_program_exit(child_pid,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dialog.py", line 1489, in _handle_program_exit
    self._wait_for_program_termination(child_pid,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dialog.py", line 1435, in _wait_for_program_termination
    raise DialogError(
dialog.DialogError: dialog-like terminated due to an error: the dialog-like program exited with status 3 (which was passed to it as the DIALOG_ERROR environment variable). Sometimes, the reason is simply that dialog was given a height or width parameter that is too big for the terminal in use. Its output, with leading and trailing whitespace stripped, was:

Error: Expected at least 5 tokens for --menu, have 4.
```

So, how can I correct this?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: I have used protonvpn unhindered for past 6 months

Comment: How to uninstall for a fresh reinstall?

Comment: Have you tried reconfiguring the VPN with `sudo protonvpn init`?

Comment: Yes, same result